# How to add self defined environment to verbatim environments

Tags: verbatim, emacs

Using the following code in emacs configuration file makes the listed environment as verbatim.

```
(setq LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local '("Verbatim" "lstlisting"))
```

How can I add following environment to this list.

```
\lstnewenvironment{code}[2][]{%
 \lstset{#1}%
 \mdframed[style=lstlisting,title={#2}]%
}{\endmdframed}
```

I have tried the following but its not working

```
(setq LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local '("Verbatim" "lstlisting" "code"))
```

Comment: Did you evaluate that code or restart Emacs?

Comment: @giordano Yes. I restarted emacs after modifying emacs configuration file but the effect was same as before.

Comment: @giordano The intention is to make the code environment as verbatim so that I can use symbols like _ in my code environment. But when I specify the argument to code environment, emacs doesn't recognize this environment as verbatim any more. For e.g. 
\begin{code}{hi} 
some_code
\end{code}

Comment: @giordano Specifically when I specify a command in that argument. For exmple. \begin{code}{\texttt{S\char`_h} some_code \end{code}

Answer (score 2):

For `emacs -Q`, @giordano's suggestion of restarting emacs should have worked, though all I had to do was evaluate

```
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments "code")
```

and run `M-x LaTeX-mode` again.

Comment: If file parsing is enabled this isn't even needed ;-)

Comment: If this is true, then I have some impossible bug reports for the mailing list :-)

Comment: Well, yes, it should.  If this isn't the case for you, please report the bug :-)