# Awk code in minted broke the whole document

Tags: emacs, minted

My whole document broken after putting awk code inside [minted](https://github.com/gpoore/minted)

[image]

I try to use python code instead, and it works fine. I also tried to remove that awk code and it also works.

The first block of minted code works fine, but why the awk code section is broken.

I tried to indent the awk correctly, tried to add `{minted}{awk}`, `{minted}{Awk}`, but nothing works.

**Update 1** : 
Using `begin{minted}{awk}` does not work. 
One workaround is to prevent all document to be highlighted is to escape `$` in awk code. and invoke latex with `--shell-escape flag`

```
  {
    files+=\$1;
    inserted+=\$4;
    deleted+=\$6;
  }
```

but the escape `\$` will appear in produced pdf.

```
% Created 2018-02-19 Mon 03:33
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{minted}
\author{azzamsa}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\section{\emph{Foo} Bar}

\subsection{Baz}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Nullam nec neque vel ipsum gravida finibus

\begin{minted}{awk}
  {
    files+=$1;
    inserted+=$4;
    deleted+=$6;
  }
  END {
    print "files changed : ", files
    print "lines inserted: ", inserted
    print "lines deleted : ", deleted
  }
\end{minted}

Sed aliquam turpis justo. Curabitur nec tortor neque. Vestibulum porta at nulla nec auctor

\end{document}
```

Comment: please don't post an image of code, it's impossible to debug that, post a small complete document that has the problem, also what error message or output did you get? "my whole document broken" is not very informative

Comment: that said `\begin{minted}` has a required argument to say the language parser to use, and you have not used that argument in either case. it should be `\begin{minted}{awk}` or some such. and something like `\begin{minted}{sh}`  for the first

Comment: Nothing is “broken” except for the syntax highlighting. What editor are you using?

Comment: I can produce right pdf after using `-shell-escape`. but I still don't know how to escape `$` in awk.
I use Emasc 24.5.1 with Auctex 11.91.0

Comment: your example runs without error and produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vkwt.png) in what way do you want the output to change?

Comment: You have to declare `minted` as a verbatim environment. I guess this is more a question for Emacs.SE than TeX.SX.

Comment: I have `(setq LaTeX-verbatim-environments '("verbatim" "Verbatim" "lstlisting"  "minted"))` in my `.emacs` file (actually `Preferences.el`, as I use Aquamacs).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241077/how-to-add-self-defined-environment-to-verbatim-environments

Comment: thank you everyone, thank you @DavidCarlisle, thank you @egreg latex community is very kind to beginner. thanks lot. the problem solved after I follow @egreg instruction by adding [this line](https://github.com/azzamsa/emacs.d/blob/13baf9c4be466e524e97b860b028e6beba26f433/init.el#L596) to my `init.el`